# Sort settings in vscode's json-based settings editor

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings

I use vscode's original settings editor (`"workbench.settings.editor": "json"`) because it gives me more control.

[image: screenshot]

The problem is the tree on the left - which contains internal settings and extensions settings - is not sorted in alpha order. It's very hard to use.

On the vscode repo [they've indicated](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/43670#issuecomment-420841680) they will not fix it because they're focusing on the new UI instead.

There must be a way to sort it. Does anyone know how (other than writing a new extension)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of 1.59.0 they've completely [removed](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/125952#issue-917705621) the split json settings editor.

So this bug is now irrelevant.

If you want those features ported to the new settings editor, **[upvote this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/130457)**. They will ignore it unless people show interest.

Answer (score 11):

**Yes**, we can easily sort the vs code JSON settings using the build in functionality of ***Sort Document***, just open the JSON setting file in editor view and open command palette using shortcut `ctrl+shift+p` or `cmd+shift+p`
then type **sort document (refer below SS)** and hit enter.
[image]

## DEMO:

My VS Code JSON setting

###### Before sorting document:

```
{
  "cSpell.userWords": ["esbenp", "Monokai"],
  "#terminal.integrated.profiles.osx#": "bash",
  "chat.editor.fontSize": 11,
  "debug.console.fontSize": 10,
  "settingsSync.ignoredSettings": ["workbench.colorTheme"],
  "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
  "workbench.sideBar.location": "right",
  "workbench.tree.indent": 2,
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "tab.activeBackground": "#008080"
  },

  "editor.fontSize": 11,
  "editor.guides.bracketPairs": true,
  "editor.cursorBlinking": "expand",
  "editor.minimap.maxColumn": 30,
  "editor.wordWrap": "on",
  "editor.renderWhitespace": "all",
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
  "editor.tabSize": 2,
  "editor.fontFamily": "fira code, 'Courier New', monospace",
  "editor.fontLigatures": true,
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[typescript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[scss]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[css]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[json]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[jsonc]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[markdown]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 10,
  "markdown.preview.fontSize": 10,
  "scm.inputFontSize": 11,
  "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
  "tabnine.experimentalAutoImports": true,
  "files.eol": "\n"
}
```

###### After sorting document:

```
{
  "#terminal.integrated.profiles.osx#": "bash",
  "[css]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[json]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[jsonc]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[markdown]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[scss]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[typescript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "chat.editor.fontSize": 11,
  "cSpell.userWords": ["esbenp", "Monokai", "tabnine"],
  "debug.console.fontSize": 10,
  "editor.cursorBlinking": "expand",
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "editor.fontFamily": "fira code, 'Courier New', monospace",
  "editor.fontLigatures": true,
  "editor.fontSize": 11,
  "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.guides.bracketPairs": true,
  "editor.minimap.maxColumn": 30,
  "editor.renderWhitespace": "all",
  "editor.tabSize": 2,
  "editor.wordWrap": "on",
  "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
  "files.eol": "\n",
  "markdown.preview.fontSize": 10,
  "scm.inputFontSize": 11,
  "settingsSync.ignoredSettings": ["workbench.colorTheme"],
  "tabnine.experimentalAutoImports": true,
  "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 10,
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "tab.activeBackground": "#008080"
  },
  "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
  "workbench.sideBar.location": "right",
  "workbench.tree.indent": 4
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: That sorts json... But it doesn't address the problem in the json editor - **the tree on the left.**

Comment: @lonix on left side on the picture in question is json, 'tree on the left' what actually you mean by this, are you referring the right side of image..?

Comment: The left side is read only. It cannot be sorted. Try it for yourself. Your effort is noted, but it doesn't answer the question. The accepted answer is correct, namely, it cannot be done, and won't be done because they refuse to fix it.

Comment: Before sorting, need to remove all the trailing commas in the settings.json. To do so: 1) add Prettier as a default formatter : "[jsonc]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  } 2) Format settings.json (it will remove all the trailing commas) 3) And after you can apply Sort document.